# Linux shell script Assignment

Tags: linux, bash

hi i wrote a program for this question :

When a person works for someone else or company, (s) he is then said to hold a job and is called Employee. The person or the company he or she works for is called Employer. Money that is paid is called as Salary or Income or Wage.  The salary consists of following part:
Basic Salary: As the name suggests, this forms the very basis of salary and many other components may be calculated based on this amount. It usually depends on one’s grade within the company’s salary structure. It is a fixed part of one’s compensation structure. 
(Allowance: It is the amount received by an individual paid by his/her employer in addition to salary to meet some service requirements such as Dearness Allowance (DA), House Rent Allowance (HRA), Leave Travel Assistance (LTA), Lunch Allowance, Conveyance Allowance, Children’s Education Allowance, and City compensatory Allowance etc.) Allowance can be fully taxable, partly or non-taxable. Provident Fund (PF) Contribution is made for the employee's welfare by the employer. The deduction is based on PF and Income Tax (IT). Try to understand the components of the salary structure and taxation for more details.

- Using the proper shell scripting, calculate the net salary of an employee. Basic Salary, DA, HRA, TA and Other Allowances (OA) are given.  Follow the constraints and find out the amount to be deducted using the proper PF and IT calculation.
  Basic salary: $ 15000
  DA: 14% of Basic salary
  HRA: $175
  TA: $150
  other allowances (OA): $400
  Deduction – a) PF: 12% of Basic salary and b) IT: 15% of Basic salary
  Net Salary = Basic Salary + DA + HRA + TA + OA – (PF + IT)

but this is not working
please help me 
thank you so mush

the program is :

```
echo "please enter Basic Salary"
read basic 
echo "please enter your HRA"
read HRA
echo "please enter your TA"
read TA 
echo "please enter your OA"
read OA
DA echo = "scale=3, $basic*0.14" | bc 
PF echo = "scale=3, $basic*0.12" | bc 
IT echo = "scale=3, $basic*0.15" | bc 
echo "DA is: $DA"
echo "PF is: $PF"
echo "TA is: $IT"
Ns = echo "scale=3: $basic + $DA + $HRA + $TA + $OA + : bc 
echo "Net salary: $ NA "
```

Comment: There's a lot wrong here with the syntax. Dump it into [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for some nice automated help. Consider assigning variables based on output of a command like `DA=$(echo  "scale=3, $basic*0.14" | bc)`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "please enter Basic Salary"
read basic 
echo "please enter your HRA"
read HRA
echo "please enter your TA"
read TA 
echo "please enter your OA"
read OA

DA = $basic\*0.14
PF = $basic\*0.12 
IT= $basic\*0.15 

echo "DA is: $DA"
echo "PF is: $PF"
echo "TA is: $IT"
Ns=$basic+$DA+$HRA+$TA+$OA-$PF-$IT
echo "Net salary: $NS"


enter code here
```